# How to pass actual values to minimist instead of key-value?

Tags: javascript, node.js, command-line, command-line-arguments, minimist

https://www.npmjs.com/package/minimist

For **some** keys I want to be able pass actual variables of them instead:

```
$ node my_script.js --var1 a --var2 b --var3 c
```

===>

```
$ node my_script.js --var1 a --b --var3 c
$ node my_script.js --var1 a --b1 --var3 c
$ node my_script.js --var1 a --b2 --var3 c
```

Where `(b, b1, b2, ... bN)` -- is a predefined set of constants.

How to do it? Is it possible at all?

Comment: `--b`, `--b1` and `--b2` are essentially independent boolean flags. Interpreting them as values for a `var2` variable (and handling the cases where none or multiple of them are supplied) needs to be done by your application, that's out of scope for minimist.